# HOSTUNREACH error when trying to connect from Android to Linux on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, ssh, android, raspberry-pi

I'm having trouble getting any of the Android SSH clients to work.  I've tried a few including the two most popular JuiceSSH and ConnectBot.  They all give the same error HOSTUNREACH.

Android is running on a Galaxy Tab 10.1 connecting over Wifi to my home network.

I am able to SSH to the Raspberry Pi without a problem on both a desktop PC running Windows 7, and a laptop also running Windows 7, both of which also connect over Wifi (the desktop has a Wifi dongle).

It would seem the problem is with the tablet device, but I'm clueless as to how to debug this problem (which seems like a network connectivity problem) on Android.

Appreciate any help/suggestions on what to try.  The Raspberry Pi is connected directly to the Wifi router via Cat5.

Thanks,

**EDIT**

I have this working now but only by using the public IP address, and port forwarding on the router to forward port 22 to the Raspberry Pi.

I still don't know why it doesn't work internally.

Comment: Are you ssh-ing with ip address or hostname?

Comment: @Paul I'm using an IP address

Comment: If it works via the public IP address and not internally, I would guess that you are not actually connected to your wifi network.  If you go to `Settings / About phone / Status` is the IP address shown in your internal range?

Comment: @Paul Yes, the IP address is shown as 192.168.X.X on the tablet device.  The tablet's only connectivity is via Wifi, so it has to go via the router to access the internet, and hence the public IP (which is working).

Comment: Very weird.  Did you set the IP of the tablet by hand, or it is dhcp?  The only thing I can think of is a subnet mask mismatch, or you have something on the pi blocking local IP addresses and only allowing internet ones.

Comment: @Paul Yeah it's using DHCP. I don't think it's the Pi blocking local IP addresses because my desktop pc (which also connects over Wifi via a dongle) has no problems connecting locally.

Comment: Can you ping the android device from the pi?

Answer (score 0):

It might be your DNS address on the Wireless Access Point. I had the same problem and when I looked at my access point I notice it was using the wrong DNS address. I put in the correct DNS and everything worked. I could connect from JuiceSSH to the Raspberry Pi. Hope this helps.